# Detect If Two Buttons Are Held Down

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an endless runner game for android and using UI button to move player Left and Right. I want to make the player jump when I press both left & right UI button. Here is my player movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public float speed = 15;
    public float diSpeed = 20; 
         
    public Rigidbody rb;
    CharacterController characterController;

    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;

    float horizontalInput;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 forwardMove = transform.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Vector3 horizontalMove = transform.right * moveVector.x * diSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + forwardMove + horizontalMove);
    }

    void Update()
    {
       
        moveVector.x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       
    }
}
```

Game view representing UI buttons:

[image: Game view representing UI buttons]

Answer (score 1):

## try this

```cs
private float cooldownL; // give it a little cooldown so you dont have to press both
private float cooldownR; // buttons at the exact same frame
private bool isLeftPressed;
private bool isRightPressed

void Update(){
  cooldownR -= Time.deltaTime;
  cooldownL -= Time.deltaTime;
  if(cooldownR < 0){cooldownR = 0;}
  if(cooldownL < 0){cooldownL = 0;}

  if(isLeftPressed = true)
    movement = -1;
  }        
  if(isRightPressed = true)
    movement = 1;
  }
  if(cooldownL != 0 && cooldownR)
    // jump
  }
}
public void LeftPress(){
    isLeftPressed = true;
    cooldownL = 0.8f;
}
public void RightPress(){
    isRightPressed = true;
    cooldownR = 0.8f;
}
```

here is how to assign your button with the script:

> First, select your ui button. In there go to the "on click" section
> and add an event. Select the object with your script assigned. Under
> "No Function" select your scriptname and then go to "leftPress()" or
> right depending on which button.
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: assign the LeftPress Method to the left UI button
and the RightPress Method to the right UI button

i added a cooldown so you dont have to press them in the exact same millisecond, but almost a second is quit long depending on what kind of game, the movement variable is just a placeholder for you to put down your movement.

Comment: How i can assign leftpress method to UIbutton??

Comment: its so easy: you go to the hierarchy then select your button, and in the Inspector you see the "button" component, scroll down a bit and there you find the "OnClick" Event. Create a new event and drag the object who got the script assigned. then choose the script and then select the function "leftPress()"

Comment: just check the updated answer, there it is with pictures